# Is $1\underbrace{0101\cdots 01}_{k\text{ 01}}$ composite for all $k \geq 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is $$1\underbrace{0101\cdots 01}_{k\text{ 01}}$$ composite for all $k \geq 2$?

when $k=2,3$ . they are composite numbers.

$$10101 = 3\times 7\times 13\times 37$$

$$1010101 = 73\times 101\times 137$$

Comment: Are you asking whether or not there is a prime number of this form?  Pretty easy to check that they aren't all prime.

Comment: @DanielR I guess number in this pattern is not a prime.  : )

Comment: @lulu yes. I think they are all composite numbers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of these are prime.  To see that we write your numbers as $$S_k=1+10^2+10^4+\cdots+10^{2k}=\frac {10^{2k+2}-1}{10^2-1}=\frac {(10^{k+1}+1)(10^{k+1}-1)}{99}$$

To conclude we remark that for large $k$ it is clear that both factors in the numerator are larger than $99$.